# how to check null or undefined values in local storage of ionic and redirect to login page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

Here is my code here iam checking the null or undefined values or "" like this

i want to check for loggedin or not in ionic v1 app.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function () {
    var items = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
    if (items === undefined || items === null || items.length === 0) {


        return '/app/login';


    }
    else {


        return '/app/search';


    }


});
```

and also tried this

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("username") === null) {

      console.log($localStorage.username);
      $scope.username = $localStorage.username;
  }
```

but no luck 
here am setting the value like this after login

```
$localStorage.username = $scope.userinfo.username;
```

clearing the local storage items like this

```
  localStorage.removeItem("username");
  $window.localStorage.clear();
  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
```

here the problem is every time the app is redirected to login page even though the item username is set or user logged in. What could be the solution please help me iam new to this ionic and angularjs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("username") === null` should work...if is not, you probably have an empty string inside it. use `console.log` to check the value you have on `localStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `$localStorage.username = $scope.userinfo.username;`. The `localStorage.username` doesn't seem to get set properly. You can try instead:

`window.localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.userinfo.username);`

Also, check if `$scope.userinfo.username` has the right value at the time you are doing the saving.

EDIT: Btw, I hope you are clearing the `localstorage.username` only on user logout, right?

Comment: Thank you very much man it worked i have been scratching my head from 2days. BTW I am using this localStorage.removeItem("username");
  $window.localStorage.clear();
  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory(); on logout is it the correct way to do it.

Comment: It's okay if it's only on logout.  I asked since your problem might have originated from the fact that you might have called that some other times too. But if it's fixed, then it's all good.

Comment: Thank you very much